# Visual Studio Freezing / Blackscreen when running a program

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm currently programming my Pixel Drawer Software in WPF (.NET C#). At a specific point when I try to compile and run my solution, Visual Studio is freezing for about 10 seconds, then I have a short blackscreen (with some pixel errors). After 15 seconds at all, my program is finally running. When I restart my computer, it is fixed (apparently), at some point the whole process starts again.

I really need help because it is very annoying to restart your computer every hour.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As your question is currently written it is difficult to understand where you are having a problem. If this is a problem with code, it would be helpful if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can run. If it is about Visual Studio, you should include the `visual-studio` tag, the version, and make it clear when the problem occurs (during compile, debug, etc). Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to ensure it has the most relevant details.

Comment: It seems that its caused by the size of your RAM. Whats the size of your RAM? 4GB?

Comment: No I have 16 GB Ram.